# How to make a while-loop run as long as an element is present on page using selenium in python?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm struggling with creating a `while`-loop which runs as long as a specific element is present on a website. What I currently have is by no means a solution I'm proud of, but it works. I would however very much appreciate some suggestions on how to change the below:

```
def spider():
    url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask'
    driver.get()

    while True:
        try:
            unique_element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("uniqueclass")

            do_something()

        except NoSuchElementException:
            print_data_to_file(entries)
            break

    do_something_else()
```

As you can see, the first thing I do within the `while`-loop is to check for a unique element which is only present on pages containing data I'm interested in. Thus, when I reach a page without this information, I'll get the `NoSuchElementException` and break.

How can I achieve the above without having to make a `while True`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`driver.find_elements` won't throw any error. If the returned list is empty it means there aren't any more elements

```
def spider():
    url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask'
    driver.get()

    while len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("uniqueclass")) > 0:
        do_something()

do_something_else()
```

You could also use explicit wait with expected condition [staleness_of](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.staleness_of), however you won't be able to execute `do_something()` and it's used for short waiting periods.

Comment: Could also just be `while driver.find_elements_by_class_name("uniqueclass"):`. Also depending on what happens inside `do_something()` a little `sleep` might be good.

Comment: I appreciate your answers - I'll give it a try!